# \include not working. Folder structure too deep?

Tags: include

I wrote `\include{{"Folder_A/B/C/D/M"}}`. LaTeX reported that it could not write the 'Folder_A/B/C/D/M.aux' file. 
Is it because my file is too deep? 
Any idea? THX!
OK. Someone told me this short version could work, then how about the long version of my path? 
`Literature_review/ABCDEFG/ABCDEFG/ABCDEF_ab_ABCDEFGHIJKL_abc_ABCDEFGH/ABCD_ABCDEFG_ab_ABCDEFGHIJKL_abc_ABCDEFGH`? That could represent the length of my path. I'm using the online editor Sharelatex.
The error message was:

```
\@include ...\immediate \openout \@partaux #1.aux 
                          \immediate \write \@partau...
l.6 ...s/ABCD_ABCDEFG_ab_ABCDEFGHIJKL_abc_ABCDEFGH}

(Press Enter to retry, or Control-D to exit; default file extension is `.tex') 
Please type another output file name ! Emergency stop.
\@include ...\immediate \openout \@partaux #1.aux 
                          \immediate \write \@partau...
l.6 ...s/ABCD_ABCDEFG_ab_ABCDEFGHIJKL_abc_ABCDEFGH}
```

By the way, someone said I should use this format `\include{Folder_A/B/C/D/M}` instead of `\include{{"Folder_A/B/C/D/M"}}`. Neither of them would work. The format I used was to preserve the file path. It doesn't matter. If the first format could work, then the second would work too.

OK. The file looks like:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

%\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{"Research_report/XXXX_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX_XXXXXX/Images/"}}
\usepackage{ccaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[capposition=bottom]{floatrow}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage[euler]{textgreek}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin*{chapter}{part}

\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.0pt}

\usepackage[sort, authoryear]{natbib}
%\bibliographystyle{dinat}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
%\usepackage[duplicate]{chapterbib}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}

\fancyhead[RE]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{Page \thepage}

\begin{document}

\input{titlepage}
\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage
\setcounter{page}{1}

\input{abstract}

\tableofcontents

\part{Literature review}
\fancyhead[LO]{\chaptername\ \thechapter}
\input{"Literature_review/main_Lit_Rev.tex"}


\part{Research report}
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\fancyhead[LO]{\chaptername\ \thechapter}
\input{"Research_report/main_Res_Rep.tex"}

\clearpage
\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\rightmark}

\bibliography{References.bib}

\end{document}
```

And this is part of my main_Lit_Rev.tex

```
\chapter {XXXXXX ab \textit{XXXXXXXXXX} abc \textit{XXXXXXXX}}
\include{{"Literature_review/ABCDEFG/ABCDEFG/ABCDEF_ab_ABCDEFGHIJKL_abc_ABCDEFGH/ABCD_ABCDEFG_ab_ABCDEFGHIJKL_abc_ABCDEFGH"}}
% This code below doesn't work either 
% \include{Literature_review/ABCDEFG/ABCDEFG/ABCDEF_ab_ABCDEFGHIJKL_abc_ABCDEFGH/ABCD_ABCDEFG_ab_ABCDEFGHIJKL_abc_ABCDEFGH}
```

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue setting a similar path. All is well for me. Please read this [guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) and this [guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) to learn about our style.

Comment: @OSjerick: Sorry. How about this then `Literature_review/ABCDEFG/ABCDEFG/ABCDEF_ab_ABCDEFGHIJKL_abc_ABCDEFGH/ABCD_ABCDEFG_ab_ABCDEFGHIJKL_abc_ABCDEFGH`? That could represent the length of my path.

Comment: Please provide a minimal file showing the exact problem. You'd need to tell us the exact layout.

Comment: You might getting the message because your *operating system* doesn't allow writing in the directory?

Comment: @David Carlisle: I edited my original post.

Comment: @David Carlisle: It doesn't matter. When one uses `\include{{ }}`, it just tells LaTeX to preserve the file name. Otherwise if there is some spaces in the file name, the file will not be included.

Comment: @vonbrand: I edited my original post with the minimal file.

Comment: @fyang No, the extra braces do not have that effect in latex  (unless you are using luatex) (and even in luatex they would not have that effect with `\include` as they are dropped due to macro argument processing.

Comment: That is in no sense minimal!

Comment: @cfr: I don't know if it was any of those packages that caused the problem. I need to post them here.

Comment: @David Carlisle: I'm using the online editor Sharelatex. I don't know what they use behind the editor.

Comment: No you don't need to post them. Test to see if they are responsible. If not, omit them. You don't want `\chapter{}\include{}`. You want the `\chapter` in the included file. (This isn't the problem, but it is nonetheless true. `\include{}` always issues a new page.)

Comment: I'll figure out what I can delete while still producing the same problem later.

Comment: Reducing the problem to the minimal case *usually* gets you the culprit.

Comment: I'm confused now. When I tried to re-create the same folder structure and files, it worked. But I don't know it couldn't with the original project.

Comment: `\include{}` should be used only for something like an entire chapter. You shouldn't nest it this way.

Answer (score 2):

In your question you told us the path would be something like this:

```
Literature_review/ABCDEFG/ABCDEFG/ABCDEF_ab_ABCDEFGHIJKL_abc_ABCDEFGH/ABCD_ABCDEFG_ab_ABCDEFGHIJKL_abc_ABCDEFGH
%                                                               ^^^^^
```

but in the cited error message I saw:

```
l.6 ...s/ABCD_ABCDEFG_ab_ABCDEFGHIJKL_abc_ABCDEFGH
%   ^^^^
```

Where does the `...s` come from?  I think the **error is hidden** in this `s` part not shown to us.

I guess at last you have a special character in your path disturbing the system, like à, é etc.

If this guess does not help you, please show us the **real** path you used, and please **complete** it! (for windows: `c:\mylatex\...GH`)

Without better informations more I can not say ...